# iOS 5 : simple audio controls with AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: audio, navigation, avaudioplayer

I just begun to code iOS apps with xCode and it's not very easy nor intuitive to find how things work. I'm very new into this and my app goes on very slowly... :P

I managed to create dynamic tables with customs cells and dynamic height but now I don't find any solution to my problem... Maybe I didn't search at the right place... anyway.

I have an audio playing, thanks to these lines:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
    initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil];

[audio play];
[audio updateMeters];
```

Now, that's great, my audio plays. But I don't have any controls. I successfully added a play/pause button, but how to navigate inside the audio? Do I have to code **ALL** the interface? There isn't a simple interface with a button and a responsive progress bar?

And if I have to code it, well, hum... where do I start?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Side note - If you just started with iOS and Xcode then why are you writing for iOS 5? iOS 7 is out. Use the latest tools.

Comment: Well, it's for an internal project and we have already 30 iPod Touch on iOS 5. Maybe we can upgrade them to iOS 6, but we would like to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I'm giving up on iOS 5. I posted the same question but on iOS 7 here:
[link to iOS7 question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638497/ios-7-simple-audio-controls-with-avaudioplayer)