# Slider Control with AVPlayer Swift 2

Tags: swift, parse-platform, avaudioplayer, avplayer, uislider

I am using Parse to stream audio to my iOS device, I would like to add a slider which would monitor and change the progress of the audio being played.

I have to stream the audio with AVPlayer, is there a way to change the progress of the audio track with a slider or do I have to change it into the AVAudioPlayer format (which I don't know how to do either)?

```
let audioQuery = PFQuery(className: "Audio")
audioQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(IDArray[selectedPodcast], block: {

    (object : PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
    if let audioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("AudioFile")?.url as String! {

        audioURL = audioFileURLTemp

        audioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: audioFileURLTemp)!)
        audioPlayer.play()

    }

})
```

This is the code I am using to stream the audio

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by change the progress? Do you mean you want to be able to use the slider as a scrubber to see to certain parts of the audio track? AVPlayer has a very accurate `seekToTime()` if that is the case. You could connect it to your UISlider

Comment: yeah, thats exactly what i need, how would I implement that? if you don't mind showing me some example code?

Comment: I can post an answer but I don't have time right now, very sorry. Here is the gist: create a UISlider in storyboard or programmatically. Connect the slider to an @IBAction or to a `selector` if you made the slider programatically. The selector(or IBAction) is called anytime the slider is moved. So inside the selector, you will do `audioPlayer.seekToTime(//input value of slider on scale from 0 thru songDuration)`. This way, when slider is moved, audioPlayer will jump to the time that the slider is at. Note: `seekToTime()` takes a CMTime as an argument, so you must convert the # to a CMTime.

Comment: Great thanks, ive got it working!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use: `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:`

I used the following block to play a movie:

```
let sliderWidth = CGRectGetWidth(movieSlider.bounds)
let interval = Double(movieSelected.original.duration.value * 1000)/Double(movieSelected.original.duration.timescale) / Double(sliderWidth)
player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(interval/1000, 1000), queue: nil) { (time: CMTime) -> Void in
   self.movieSlider.value = Float(time.value) / Float(time.timescale) / Float(self.movieSelected.original.duration.value) * Float(self.movieSelected.original.duration.timescale)
}
```

Comment: I get the error 'AVPlayer' has no member 'original'

Comment: Sorry the above code is a dump from a project I worked on quite a while ago. As mentioned it was for playing a movie. I suggest you use the AVAudioPlayer class for playing audio. Refer link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638497/ios-7-simple-audio-controls-with-avaudioplayer

Comment: I do not know how to convert the file to an AVAuidoPlayer because the file is being streamed from Parse.com, and that link is for Obj-C but thanks anyway